# Heroku Flask Tutorial Procfile Meaning

Tags: python, heroku, flask

In the heroku [tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python-o), there is a piece of code

**hello.py**

```
import os
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return 'Hello World!'
```

and a Procfile:

`web: gunicorn hello:app --log-file=-`

The part that's really confusing is the `hello:app` part; does `hello` refer to the `hello()` function or the **hello.py** script? Depending on the meaning of that, what does the whole Procfile statement mean?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

tl;dr: `hello` refers to `hello.py` and `app` refers to `app = Flask(__name__)`

---

The mentioned Heroku tutorial is no more available, however [Gunicorn's doc](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/run.html#gunicorn) gives a good minimal example :

> Example with the test app:
>
> ```
> def app(environ, start_response):
>     """Simplest possible application object"""
>     data = b'Hello, World!\n'
>     status = '200 OK'
>     response_headers = [
>         ('Content-type', 'text/plain'),
>         ('Content-Length', str(len(data)))
>     ]
>     start_response(status, response_headers)
>     return iter([data])
> ```
>
> You can now run the app with the following command:
>
> `$ gunicorn --workers=2 test:app`

---

Let's try, my *test-directory* looks like this :

```
(.venv) 14:41 ~/testgunicorn % tree
.
├── requirements.txt
└── testpkg
    ├── __init__.py
    └── testfile.py
```

**`__init__.py`** :

```
from flask import Flask
from .testfile import app
```

**`testfile.py`** :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

def app(environ, start_response):
    """Simplest possible application object"""
    data = b'Hello, World!\n'
    status = '200 OK'
    response_headers = [
        ('Content-type', 'text/plain'),
        ('Content-Length', str(len(data)))
    ]
    start_response(status, response_headers)
    return iter([data])
```

**Wrong calling** :

```
(.venv) 14:41 ~/testgunicorn % gunicorn testfile:app         
[2018-08-24 14:41:44 +0200] [27248] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.9.0
[2018-08-24 14:41:44 +0200] [27248] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (27248)
[2018-08-24 14:41:44 +0200] [27248] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2018-08-24 14:41:44 +0200] [27251] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 27251
[2018-08-24 14:41:44 +0200] [27251] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "~/testgunicorn/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "~/testgunicorn/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 129, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "~/testgunicorn/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 138, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "~/testgunicorn/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "~/testgunicorn/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "~/testgunicorn/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 41, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "~/testgunicorn/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 350, in import_app
    __import__(module)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'testfile'
[2018-08-24 14:41:44 +0200] [27251] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 27251)
[2018-08-24 14:41:44 +0200] [27248] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
[2018-08-24 14:41:44 +0200] [27248] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
zsh: exit 3     gunicorn testfile:app
```

**Good callings** :

```
(.venv) 14:43 ~/testgunicorn % gunicorn testpkg:app 
[2018-08-24 14:43:56 +0200] [27302] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.9.0
[2018-08-24 14:43:56 +0200] [27302] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (27302)
[2018-08-24 14:43:56 +0200] [27302] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2018-08-24 14:43:56 +0200] [27305] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 27305
^C
(…)

(.venv) 15:03 ~/testgunicorn % cd testpkg    
(.venv) 15:03 fred@susa ~/git/ocp7/testpkg % gunicorn testfile:app
[2018-08-24 15:03:22 +0200] [27494] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.9.0
[2018-08-24 15:03:22 +0200] [27494] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (27494)
[2018-08-24 15:03:22 +0200] [27494] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2018-08-24 15:03:22 +0200] [27497] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 27497
^C
(…)
```

---

Then for this `Procfile` :

`web: gunicorn hello:app --log-file=-`

> Does hello refer to the hello() function or the hello.py script?

To the `hello.py` script

> Depending on the meaning of that, what does the whole Procfile statement mean?

Heroku's [Procfile format documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile#procfile-format) says :

> A Procfile declares its process types on individual lines, each with
>   the following format:
>
> `<process type>: <command>`
>
> - `<process type>` is an alphanumeric name for your command, such as web, worker, urgentworker, clock, and so on.
> - `<command>` indicates the command that every dyno of the process type should execute on startup, such as rake jobs:work.

The `--logfile=-` option seems to be deprecated, I did not find anything about it in documentation and if I use it I get this error :

```
(.venv) 15:34 ~/testgunicorn % heroku local web
[WARN] No ENV file found
15:34:30 web.1   |  usage: gunicorn [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]
15:34:30 web.1   |  gunicorn: error: unrecognized arguments: --logfile=-
15:34:30 web.1   Exited with exit code 2
```

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32411082/6709630) it was an option for logging in Heroku's stdout.

Answer (score 8):

The ProcFile contains the command line for starting your application on heroku. The full documentation can be found here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile

In this case it is telling heroku to use the  app variable (your constructed flask app) in the hello module with gunicorn and to start a web process (one that can handle http requests). There are other process types you can specify such as background workers.

Your flask application object is a  WSGI application, and can be run using any WSGI server.  Gunicorn is just one of the choices on heroku.

Answer (score 2):

1-
According to [Heroku doc](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile) section **Procfile format**

```
web: gunicorn hello:app
```

is a <process type>: <command> pattern

2- `web` is therefore the <process type>. According to the same [documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile): "A Heroku app’s web process type is the only process type that can receive external HTTP traffic from Heroku’s routers. If your app includes a web server, you should declare it as your app’s web process."

3- Now the <command> part:

```
gunicorn hello:app
```

If you look in the [gunicorn doc](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/run.html#gunicorn) section *basic usage*  you will see that a typical command  for gunicorn is

```
$ gunicorn [OPTIONS] APP_MODULE
```

Where APP_MODULE is of the pattern $(MODULE_NAME):$(VARIABLE_NAME).

So in your example `hello` refers $(MODULE_NAME) that is hello.py. Note that it can be a full dotted path if necessary. In the same way `app` refers to a WSGI callable $(VARIABLE_NAME) that should be found in the specified hello module and actually defined when you instantiated the Flask class:
`app = Flask(__name__)`.