# Failed to find attribute 'run' in 'app' heroku

Tags: flask, heroku

[folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4gjs7.png)

mine run.py is outside of mine app folder which content all the code.

[Profile  setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gh8Qu.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Heroku Flask Tutorial Procfile Meaning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30178792/heroku-flask-tutorial-procfile-meaning)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I modify Procfile to run Gunicorn process in a non-standard folder on Heroku?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16416172/2745495)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are running Heroku instance. By the way, you better say it in question. I can guess it only after saw Procfile on screenshot. Did you set env variable?

```
heroku config:set FLASK_APP=run.py
```

Comment: Hi thanks you for the reply .... is heroku config:set FLASK_APP=run.py set in Procfile ? i need mine app to run gunicorn on heroku

Comment: no-no. you just run this command in the Heroku CLI. Or you can try to set it manually in the heroku account. You can set config variables in the heroku app settings. Try to set there FLASK_APP=run.py

Comment: this is the  reference for heroku cli https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli
good stuff