# Issues when deploying flask app to Heroku

Tags: python, flask, heroku

I have recently gone through this [flask tutorial](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/tutorial/) and am now attempting to deploy my application to heroku.

I am able to run the app locally using the command `gunicorn "platform:create_app()"`. Due to that command working I added a Procfile which contains `web: gunicorn platform.'create_app()'` but when I try to deploy to Heroku I'm receiving the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'platform.create_app()'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched around and couldn't find a really clear answer to this question, although I think [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30178792/heroku-flask-tutorial-procfile-meaning) and specifically [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63304814/17568469) might help to shed some light.

What I can tell you is that none of the Procfiles I have ever created for Flask apps to deploy in Heroku contained `.py` or parentheses.

A typical Procfile for me looks like this:

```
web: gunicorn app:app
```

Then in the same directory is the main app file `app.py` that contains a line:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
```

As far as I can tell the first `app` in the command points to the file (module) `app.py`, and the second to the variable `app` that is defined as `Flask(__name__)`.

---

So for your case the following should work:

```
web: gunicorn platform:app
```

Assuming you have a Python module named `platform.py` and then inside that file you would need to have a line

```
app = create_app()
```

The `create_app()` function in the tutorial you referenced returns a `Flask` object so that should do the job.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I think part of the issue is that my file which would be called platform.py is actually ```__init__.py``` as per the tutorial I followed. I'm not too sure how to reference this ```__init__.py``` file in the Procfile. ```web: gunicorn __init__:app``` doesn't seem right.

Comment: `__init__.py` is in a folder `flaskr` relative to the base directory containing the Procfile, right?

Create a file `app.py` in the base directory containing: `from flaskr import create_app` and `app = create_app()`, then use web: gunicorn app:app` for the Procfile.